# What is connectme.apple.com?

Tags: apple-inc

I've noticed a few sessions on my website with the referer of connectme.apple.com, however the server does not appear to exist on the internet. More specifically, this is the URL of the referer:

- **https://​connectme.apple.com/docs/DOC-781239** (Could not resolve host)

The most notable session from this referer was the following flow:

1. [Shutdown Causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/)
2. [Blog](https://georgegarside.com/blog/)
3. *back* then *forward*
4. [OS X - Blog](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/)
5. *back*
6. [iOS - Blog](https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/)
7. [OS X El Capitan Hidden Features](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/all-the-little-things-osx-el-capitan-hidden-features/)
8. *back 3x*

The sheer length of this session is intriguing given that I rarely break 3 pages per session!

The /docs/DOC-… section of the URL is similar to that which is used by Apple Support Communities docs (https://​discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-••••), but this is the only similarity I could find. Furthermore, the DOC number is far greater than any DOC number on ASC.

What is this domain for? What ‘docs’ are on this site? Can it be accessed outside of Apple?

Comment: Couldn't find whois data either

Comment: someone doing something silly with webbugs and your site?

Comment: Possibly an internal (to Apple) site?

Comment: @Kent That's what I'm presuming but I'd like something to confirm it, and even then I don't know what it's used for (docs sounds interesting) or why they'd be linking to my site.

Comment: You may want to ask at MacRumors, as you're more likely to find a loose-lipped employee over there who can confirm it. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect me is an intranet portal used by Apple. Used for internal communication and collaboration. Someone probably posted a link to your site for reference or info. Source: former contractor.